# Подскажите реализацию алгоритма

Tags: алгоритм, машинное-обучение, nlp

Вообщем стоит такая задача. Из строки выбрать конкретное слово или предсказать его порядковый номер и все это на машинном обучении. Например чтобы выбрать название символа из строки "цена акций ххх". Буду очень благодарен любим ссылкам на реализацию такого (если есть конечно) или советам и подсказкам, или хотя бы объяснению почему такое невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Перечитайте еще раз  и попытайтесь сами понять что вы написали.

"из строки выбрать конкретное слово или предсказать его порядковый номер" -  так выбрать (из того что известно),  или предсказать (т.е. -  заранее неизвестно)?

"выбрать конкретное слово" -  если оно вам известно (раз "конкретное") -  то это просто выбор - функция find(), которая возвращает  индекс подстроки в строке.

Что такое "выбрать название символа из строки" - это как? Какое название у символа "а", например?  И зачем оно вам?

И причем тут машинное обучение? Где ваша обучающая выборка? Где целевая функция?

"почему такое невозможно" - это невозможно, потому что "это" -  просто набор каких-то малосвязных слов без смысла их объединяющего.

Comment: Название акции - это символ (нет, не в значении типа данных). Цель данного вопроса и получить подсказки по целевой функции. Зачем вы написали гневный комментарий объемом больше вопроса, если даже не постарались в него вникнуть?

Comment: @Ytygok86 если честно читая ваш вопрос и вправду появляется еще больше других вопросов. Распишите пожалуйста подробней свой вопрос. Желательно привести конкретный пример, который ответит на большинство доп. вопросов.

Comment: @Ytygok86 -  да вот я как раз и постарался в него вникнуть. А другие увидев такой набор слов - просто прошли мимо. Что-бы получить ответ в первую очередь надо очень точно и корректно задать свой вопрос.  Для этого, конечно, надо потрудиться. Ну какая целевая функция при поиске в строке на совпадение???